# 1 table, many columns, one column of duplicates, remove duplicates

Tags: sql, duplicates, distinct

I have a table that has over 30 columns that I need to query and one column has duplicate entries.  How do I query the table and distinct by the one column without listing every column to display in the select.
**for example -**

```
Select * 
from Event
where subject_ID = 49
and date between '01-NOV-2019' and '14-NOV-2019'
```

This displays 100 rows but there should only be 50 rows and the case_id column is the only column to distinguish the duplicates.  I need to see all columns in the table but don't want the duplicate case_id rows and really don't want to list out all columns in the select.

**Tried**

```
select distinct case_id, * 
from event
where subject_ID = 49
and date between '01-NOV-2019' and '14-NOV-2019'
```

didn't work.

I should clarify that every other row is a duplicate. Each set of data has 2 rows and the case_id is the only data that distinguishes the duplicates.  Is there a way to say only display the odd numbered rows?

Comment: Select distinct * don't work?

Comment: what's causing your duplicate is your *

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: This question kind of makes sense. Its sounds like a typical use of using a window function to order the records within a partition, case_id. Then take the top one from each partition.

Answer (score 0):

what's causing your `distinct` is your *, you can use `row_number()` and `partition by case_id` to get `top` per `case_id`

```
select * from 
    (Select row_number() over (partition by case_id order by case_id) rn, * from Event 
        where subject_ID = 49 and date between '01-NOV-2019' and '14-NOV-2019'
    ) t1 
where t1.rn = 1
```

Comment: I should have specified that I am using Oracle SQL so I switched to rownum and I keep getting "from keyword not found"

Answer (score 0):

If you have a column and want one row for each value, you can use `row_number()`.  In the following code, `case_id` is this column:

```
Select *
from (select e.*,
             row_number() over (partition by case_id order by case_id) as seqnum
      from Event e
      where subject_ID = 49 and date between '01-NOV-2019' and '14-NOV-2019'
     ) e
where seqnum = 1;
```